# How to sort collection of file paths using c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of strings:

```
/a/b/111.txt
/a/b/c/222.txt
a/b/333.txt
a/b/c/d/444.txt
```

I want to this collection to be ordered like this:

```
/a/b/111.txt
a/b/333.txt
/a/b/c/222.txt
a/b/c/d/444.txt
```

So all `a/b` are grouped together, and so on.

Can this be done using linq? Or some other way?

Comment: Can't you just sort by `Path.GetDirectoryName(inputStringPathHere)`?

Comment: `data.OrderBy(x => x.Split('/').Length)`?

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
var input = new []
{
    @"/a/b/111.txt",
    @"/a/b/c/222.txt",
    @"a/b/333.txt",
    @"a/b/c/d/444.txt",
};
```

you can "normalize" the strings by removing the leading `/` (if any) and use that as sorting key:

```
var output = input.OrderBy(s => s.TrimStart('/')).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by removing all slashes from the string being compared:

```
items.OrderBy(item => item.Replace("/", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
 List<string> values = new List<string>();
 values.Add("/ a /b/111.txt");
 values.Add("/ a / b / c / 222.txt");
 values.Add("a / b / 333.txt");
 values.Add("a / b / c / d / 444.txt");            
 var sortedList = values.OrderBy(p => p.Count(c => c == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar || c == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar));
```

Working [`.Net Fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gvlZw6)

Comment: The problem with this solution is, eg, if you have a path like `/p/q/222.txt` at the beginning of your sequence, it can be ordered as one of the first elements